# Concurrent threads calling same method leads to duplicates in ConcurrentBag<DataRow> collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, duplicates

I have to process a large data set which takes over an hour on a single thread. I have implemented some multithreading to speed this up. Each thread handles a specific range of data with no overlap, but when they insert their results into the `ConcurrentBag<DataRow>` collection I created, there are some duplicates.

How is this possible? Any suggestions on what I could be doing better are appreciated!

Main method:

```
public static ConcurrentBag<DataRow> finalRowList = new ConcurrentBag<DataRow>(); //Create a concurrent collection of datarows so we can thread these calculations
public static DataTable results = new DataTable(); //Final datatable the datarows are added to

static void Main(string[] args)
{
//The goal is to calculate correlation between each item in list 1 against each item in list 2
List<string> Variable1List = populateVariable1List(); //Primary List of distinct items to iterate over
List<string> Variable2List = populateVariable2List(); //Secondary list of distinct items

DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 31);

//Separate threads based on alphabetic ranges so there is no overlap
Thread t1 = new Thread(() => CalculatePairCorrelation(Variable1List.Where(s => string.Compare(s, "G") < 0), Variable2List, endDate));
Thread t2 = new Thread(() => CalculatePairCorrelation(Variable1List.Where(s => string.Compare(s, "G") >= 0 && string.Compare(s, "M") < 0), Variable2List, endDate));
Thread t3 = new Thread(() => CalculatePairCorrelation(Variable1List.Where(s => string.Compare(s, "M") >= 0 && string.Compare(s, "S") < 0), Variable2List, endDate));
Thread t4 = new Thread(() => CalculatePairCorrelation(Variable1List.Where(s => string.Compare(s, "S") >= 0), Variable2List, endDate));

List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
threads.Add(t1);
threads.Add(t2);
threads.Add(t3);
threads.Add(t4);

foreach (Thread t in threads)
{
    t.Start();
}

foreach (Thread t in threads)
{
    t.Join();
}

//Add rows from finalRowList to final datatable
foreach (var dr in finalRowList)
{
    results.Rows.Add(dr);
}
}
```

CalculatePairCorrelation() code:

```
public static void CalculatePairCorrelation(IEnumerable<string> list1, IEnumerable<string> list2, DateTime endDate, int rows)
{
    foreach (var item1 in list1)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in list2)
        {                
            double r10 = CalculateCorrelation(item1, item2, endDate, 10);
            double r30 = CalculateCorrelation(item1, item2, endDate, 30);

            var dr = results.NewRow();
            dr["Item1"] = item1;
            dr["Item2"] = item2;
            dr["R10"] = r10;
            dr["R30"] = r30;

            finalRowList.Add(dr); //Add to thread-safe collection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have dups, first thing to look for - splitting mechanism. You should use queue and your problem will be solved

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: you can create bloching collection queue and in one thread do `task.run(() => {Load your queue})`. Then create 1-n consumer threads `task.run(() => {get from queue and process})`. wait for end `Task.Wait(producer, consumer1, consumer2, ....)` This guarantee you quick and reliable multi threaded processing

Comment: I implemented a global `ConcurrentQueue<string>` for the Item1 list and a new instance of the Item2 list for each thread. I still had the same amount of duplicates. I need to dig further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be related with this line, which is called in the parallel path:

```
var dr = results.NewRow();
```

Creating a `DataRow` probably mutates the underlying `DataTable`, which is not a thread-safe class.

My suggestion is to stay away from concurrent collections and manual partitioning of the data, and use instead [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/introduction-to-plinq) which is easy to use, and makes it harder for something to go wrong:

```
var resultsList = Variable1List
    .SelectMany(_ => Variable2List, (Item1, Item2) => (Item1, Item2))
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered() // Optional
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4) // Optional
    .Select(pair => (
        Item1: pair.Item1,
        Item2: pair.Item2,
        R10: CalculateCorrelation(pair.Item1, pair.Item2, endDate, 10),
        R30: CalculateCorrelation(pair.Item1, pair.Item2, endDate, 30)
    ))
    .ToList();

foreach (var result in resultsList)
{
    var dr = results.NewRow();
    dr["Item1"] = result.Item1;
    dr["Item2"] = result.Item2;
    dr["R10"] = result.R10;
    dr["R30"] = result.R30;
    results.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: I thought creating a datarow was just creating a new row with the same schema as the table. I was unaware it would actually alter the table. 

I will give this a shot and report back.

Comment: The only issue with parallel, you don't have much control. You never know how many threads are running.

Comment: @eek You're correct. Creating new row does not add this row to a table

Comment: [Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/system.data/system/Data/DataTable.cs.html#4799aa671a07bcdf) is the source code of the `DataTable.NewRow` method. From a quick look it seems that it does mutate the internal state of the class.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am not sure I saw internal state mutation

Comment: You were correct that the NewRow() call is NOT thread-safe! I changed my code to generate a concurrent collection of empty rows and then do a TryTake() when populating each one. Thanks!